# reverse() in a test only returns relative URL in a test for django-rest-framework and that causes a 404

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am trying to test the endpoints for my API by using [this](https://realpython.com/test-driven-development-of-a-django-restful-api/) guide. Specifically, this block is supposed to test the get request:

```
class GetAllPuppiesTest(TestCase):
    """ Test module for GET all puppies API """

    def setUp(self):
        Puppy.objects.create(
            name='Casper', age=3, breed='Bull Dog', color='Black')
        Puppy.objects.create(
            name='Muffin', age=1, breed='Gradane', color='Brown')
        Puppy.objects.create(
            name='Rambo', age=2, breed='Labrador', color='Black')
        Puppy.objects.create(
            name='Ricky', age=6, breed='Labrador', color='Brown')

    def test_get_all_puppies(self):
        # get API response
        response = client.get(reverse('get_post_puppies'))
        # get data from db
        puppies = Puppy.objects.all()
        serializer = PuppySerializer(puppies, many=True)
        self.assertEqual(response.data, serializer.data)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

When I try to adapt this to my own test, it looks like this:

```
from ..models import DemanderFeature, DemanderFeatureCollection

from rest_framework import status
from django.test import TestCase, Client
from django.urls import reverse

from ..serializers import DemanderFeatureCollectionSerializer

class GetAllDemanderFeatureCollections(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        DemanderFeatureCollection.objects.create(name='testdemanderfeaturecollection0')
        DemanderFeatureCollection.objects.create(name='testdemanderfeaturecollection1')

    def test_get_all_demandercollections(self):
        # get API response
        response = client.get(reverse('demandercollections-list'))
        # get data from db
        demanderfeaturecollections = DemanderFeatureCollection.objects.all()
        serializer = DemanderFeatureCollectionSerializer(demanderfeaturecollections, many=True)
        self.assertEqual(response.data, serializer.data)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

The problem is however the `reverse()` method is only returning the relative URL, (`/demandercollections/`) and then `client.get(reverse(...))` returns a 404. I don't understand how I can force it to use the actual explicit URL during testing.

I'm using Django 3.

My main urls.py looks like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include("app.urls")),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
]
```

And my module urls.py looks like this:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from app import views

# Create a router and register our viewsets with it.
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'demanders', views.DemanderFeatureViewSet)
router.register(r'demandercollections', views.DemanderFeatureCollectionViewSet, basename="demandercollections")
router.register(r'producers', views.ProducerFeatureViewSet)
router.register(r'producercollections', views.ProducerFeatureCollectionViewSet)
router.register(r'pathfinderrunconfigurations', views.PathfinderRunConfigurationViewSet)
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)

# The API URLs are now determined automatically by the router.
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

The `DemanderCollectionViewSet` in views.py looks like this:

```
class DemanderFeatureCollectionViewSet(
    mixins.CreateModelMixin,
    mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
    mixins.ListModelMixin,
    viewsets.GenericViewSet
):

    queryset = DemanderFeatureCollection.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DemanderFeatureCollectionSerializer
    lookup_field = 'name'

    @action(detail=True, methods=["get"])
    def geojson(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        demanders = DemanderFeature.objects.filter(demandercollection=self.get_object())
        return Response(serialize('geojson', demanders, geometry_field='geom', fields=('name',)))

    @action(detail=True, methods=["patch"])
    def commit(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        demandercollection = self.get_object()
        if not request.data["committed"]:
            # User is trying to "uncommit", do not allow this
            return Response("You may not un-commit a DemanderCollection. You must copy it and make modifications on the copy.", status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        demandercollection.committed = True
        demandercollection.save()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.request.user)
        return DemanderFeatureCollection.objects.filter(deleted=False).filter(owner=user).order_by("name")

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)

    def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        demandercollection = self.get_object()
        demandercollection.deleted = True
        demandercollection.save()
        return Response(f"Successfully deleted DemanderCollection.")
```

## POST ANSWER EDIT

not only was the accepted answer indeed the culprit, but it also revealed that the `DemanderFeatureCollection` objects being created must also be created with an `owner` attribute, and the `client` object must call its `login()` method to a valid user credential pair.

The test class therefore had to be updated to look like this:

```
class GetAllDemanderFeatureCollections(TestCase):
    """ Test module for GET all puppies API """

    def setUp(self):
        self.test_user = User.objects.create_user('test_user', 'a@b.com', 'test_user')
        self.other_user = User.objects.create_user('other_user', 'a@b.com', 'other_user')
        client.login(username="test_user", password="test_user")
        DemanderFeatureCollection.objects.create(name='testdemanderfeaturecollection0', owner=self.test_user)
        DemanderFeatureCollection.objects.create(name='testdemanderfeaturecollection1', owner=self.test_user)
        DemanderFeatureCollection.objects.create(name='otherdemanderfeaturecollection0', owner=self.other_user)

    def test_get_all_demandercollections_for_user(self):
        # get API response
        response = client.get(reverse('demandercollections-list'))
        # get data from db
        demanderfeaturecollections = DemanderFeatureCollection.objects.filter(owner=self.test_user).all()
        serializer = DemanderFeatureCollectionSerializer(demanderfeaturecollections, many=True)
        self.assertEqual(response.data, serializer.data)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: Add your `DemanderFeatureCollectionViewSet` class as well as the ***reference of `reverse()` function*** you have been using (point is that, there are two `reverse()` funs)

Comment: I added the import statement for `reverse()` to the test code block and also the source of `DemanderFeatureCollectionViewSet`

Comment: on basic inspection, I can see you are filtering the `get_queryset()` with some `owner` field and that may be the reason for 404 error

Comment: That appears to have been the crux of the issue. Not only was I not logging is as a test user, but the `DemanderFeatureCollection` objects were being created without an associated user as an owner (it seems I still allowed ownerless `DemanderFeatureCollection` model objects to be created which is also a problem). I created a test user in the `setUp()` method and the logged into it via `client.login()` in the `test_get_all_demandercollections()` method. Then it worked as excepted If you want to make your comment an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **`get_queryset()`** method of **`DemanderFeatureCollectionViewSet`** class you are filtering the model instances with **`owner`** field against the ***logged-in user***.

In your test-cases, you are creating the `DemanderFeatureCollection` instances ***without linking the `user`*** and hence DRF raising an HTTP 404 error. So, attaching the user to the instance and making the request with the same user will give you a proper response from the API.